# show mensaje or warning window

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

some of the data that im getting come whit duplicated fields.... i want a warning window or screen that tell me "some data is duplicated" is there any step to achieve this?

i tried to search for some step but nothing

what i need is a warning alert that say

> "there are two duplicated rows"

i tried to do it whit javaScript but it doesn´t work

i expect to have when i execute the tranformation an alert window that say
'there are 2 duplicated records'

Comment: Do you really want a HALT process ? There are several other ways you can filter out duplicate rows and make a LOG file with those records to check after the execution.

Comment: its a good idea.... dipose of a file whit the register of the duplicated records.... i will see it... but the original idea is only an alert to make the user know that there are duplicated records

Comment: The thing with a JavaScript Alert in Pentaho Data Integration, is that it's going to stop the process, open a window and wait for someone to Click 'OK'. I'll add an answer you can use for a separate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your flow of steps, before the end, or in the spot of your choice, add the following sequence of steps.

[image]

In the sort rows, add keys your table should be sorted on, ***Use these same columns, in the same order*** in the 'Unique Rows' step. For the Unique Rows step you need to configure 2 things:

1. Inside the step check 'Redirect duplicate row' and add your desired description message.
2. Right click your Unique Rows step, and click on 'Error handling...'. In this window, add the name of the new column that's going to contain the message from the Description you set.
   [image]

This way your 'Dump file' will receive an additional Column, whenever there are Duplicate rows, and these rows will have the disered message.

Also in the Excel Writer window, you can use both 'Include data in filename' and 'Include time in filename', this will create several files, but in case you need a timestamp of when these duplicate rows passed in the flow, this is a good choice. These 2 options are present in most, if not all, Output steps.

Comment: i´ll try your solution.... my project is made of 3 transformations.. all executed on a job ... now there i used a sql statement ... group the records ... if there records biggeer than 2 (duplicated) shows a msg dialog ... but like i said .. i´ll try your solution .. thanks btw

Comment: also "my" solution stop the proccess waiting for someone to click ok jaja ;)